# Validation data in Ext.Model

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Help me please.
Models have built-in support for validations, which are executed against the validator functions in Ext.data.validations. 
My code:

```
 Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'name',    
            type: 'string'
        },{
            name: 'age',
            type: 'int'
        },{
            name: 'phone',
            type: 'string'
        },{
            name: 'gender',  
            type: 'string'
        },{
            name: 'username',
            type: 'string'
        }],
        validations: [
            {
            type: 'length',   
            field: 'name',    
            min: 2
            },{
            type: 'format',   
            field: 'username',
            matcher: /([a-z]+)[0-9]{2,3}/
            }]
    });

        var person = Ext.create('User', {
        name: 'Eugene',
        username: 'Popov',
        gender: 'F',
        age: 300,
        Married: false
    });
    console.log(person.get('name'))
    person.set('name','U');
     console.log(person.get('name'))//U
});
```

I've read that the model can filter data .
What is the principle of their work?
Why I can write wrong values  in my example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model validations don't reject changes by themselves. Editing a model through some other component (like stores or grid editors) may provide this feature. Validations only come into play when calling the `validate` or `isValid` methods on a model.

If your models are part of a store, you can listen for the store's `update` event ([link to docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-update)). From within the event handler, you can validate the model and reject any changes you want.

```
// Simple demonstration
store.on('update', function (store, model, operation) {
    if (operation === Ext.data.Model.EDIT && !model.isValid()) {
        model.reject();
    }
});
```